# Why Next.js params are not passed to component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In the end of the `getStaticProps` method,

```js
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ ...context }) => {
```

I pass parameters to the component:

```js
return {
    props: {
      eventId,
      buyTicketDataBE: buyTicketDataBE
        ? buyTicketDataBE
        : "Error, no event found",
      sortedBookings: sortedBookings ?? null,
      recommendations: recommendations ?? null,
      sortedEventTimes: sortedEventTimes ?? null,
      couponRedeemString: couponRedeemString ?? null,
      translations: translations.default,
      lang: context.params?.lang ?? fallBackLang,
    },
    revalidate: buyTicketDataBE.timeElapsedSinceLastSale ?? 600,
  };
```

But in the component, is not always received.

```js
interface BuyTicketProps {
  eventId: string;
  buyTicketDataBE: BuyTicketData;
  sortedBookings: SortedBookings;
  recommendations: { [position: string]: Recommendation };
  sortedEventTimes: EventTimes;
  couponRedeemString: string;
  translations: Translation;
  lang: string;
}
function BuyTicket(props: BuyTicketProps) {
  const {
    eventId,
    buyTicketDataBE,
    sortedBookings,
    recommendations,
    sortedEventTimes,
    couponRedeemString,
    translations,
    lang,
  } = props;
  const [buyTicketData, setBuyTicketData] = useState({ ...buyTicketDataBE });
  console.log("eventId 1", eventId);
  console.log("org id 1", buyTicketData.organizationId);
```

Here these two last lise is two times called, with the following output:

```
eventId 1 undefined
org id 1 undefined
eventId 1 undefined
org id 1 undefined
eventId 1 128228399715137
org id 1 undefined
```

Strange because when I check in terminal the server renderin I can see both value is received from BE. Then why it is not passed to client?

```
eventId 1 128228399715137
org id 1 1AFEFE82-865B-47F7-8DD0-FEE5704B323D
```

Or client will not get at all those parameters?

Comment: `buyTicketData` is part of the component's state which is set/initialized when it first mounts. The props change, but there is no update to the `buyTicketData` state. You can add an `useEffect` hooks on `props.buyTicketDataBE` to `setBuyTicketData` with the new `props.buyTicketDataBE`

Comment: What I do not understand, how is that component get called with missing paramters?